# Iframe video on Android Hybrid App with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, video

I embedded a youtube video on my index.html file.

```
<iframe id="video" width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxx?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

- I created the app via cmd with Cordova Phonegap like this:

  ```
   cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
  ```
- Replaced my html,css, js files in the app folder.
- Added android platform:

  ```
   cordova platform add android
  ```
- Opened Eclipse, imported the app, and run it.
- I put the .apk on my tablet and everythings works fine, but the video doesn't work.

  I get the error "Web page not avaiable" instead of the video.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I simply added ***http:*** in link on the *src* attribute.

```
<iframe id="video" width="640" height="360" src="HTTP://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxx?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably white list youtube.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

```
<access origin="http://*.youtube.com" />
```