# How to integrate Facebook Video Social Plugin in Ionic / cordova?

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using ionic v 1.3. In which we want to use Facebook social video plugin.We integrated facebook video plugin but in that I am facing issue in ios and android App.

Here me facebook video ifarme is loaded but in that video is not rendered.

But same code is working for me for web application.

I am referring below link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" data-width="500" data-show-text="false"> 
      </div>
  </div>
```

I appreciate any help about this trouble.

Comment: You may ned to whitelist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184895/iframe-video-on-android-hybrid-app-with-phonegap

Comment: I am already done with this but still not working

Comment: I am done with another approach. Using facebook graph API getting facebook video URL which is mp4 format and Using html 5 video tag playing facebook public video.

Comment: @PopatShirsath how did you get that video in mp4? I always get a URL like: https://www.facebook.com/page/videos/1578133528874720/

Answer (score 1):

You have to put in your code this line:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```